# Recursive Search LinkedList

Tags: java, search, recursion, linked-list

I'm creating a recursive search method on a linked list and i'm getting an error and i can't even compile so don't even know if my methods are working correctly yet. My error is "The method search(E, E) in the type LinkedListRec is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedListRec, String)"

here is my code

```
private boolean search(Node<E> head,E list, E target){

if(list == null)
    return false;
else if (target.equals(head.data))
    return true;
else
    return search(head.next,list, target);
}
private boolean search(E list, E target){
return search(head, list, target);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

LinkedListRec<String> example1 = new LinkedListRec<String>();
example1.add("a");
example1.add("b");
System.out.println(example1);

System.out.println(search(example1,"b"));
```

Comment: That's true; it's not applicable. Look at the method signature and compare it to the call in main you make....

Comment: The signature takes in two generic types, and i'm trying to pass in list of string, and another string argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't, given the code, use your generic `E` as the type for *all* those parameters because they aren't all `E`s. That's the case in both search methods.

But that's not really a problem here because the search methods are already in the linked list class. So you have a couple changes to make.

1. In main call the search with `example1.search(yourString);`
2. Remove the list parameter entirely from your search methods; it's not needed.

How you'll go about searching now will be when the client calls the public search method and passes in the String or whatever `E` they choose you'll pass into your recursive helper the head of your list and the target; no list.

So the signatures will now be...

`private boolean search(Node<E> head, E target)...`

and

`public boolean search(E target)... // Needs to be public.`

Comment: I'm confused with the C, i've imported java.util.Collection. In my class header i have public class LinkedListRec<E> originally, But if i add C it would be LinkedListRec<E,C> and then i would need two types when making my list.

Comment: I wanted it to be generic because i may instead of LinkedListRec to hold string i may want another list to hold ints

Comment: Yes i created the code for search methods to belong to my LinkedListRec class

Comment: Yes, but your code is accepting a ***list*** as an `E` (the element type *held* by the list). So if you'll always be passing the same list type (`LinkedListRec`) then just change the `E list` to `LinkedListRec list`. Does that make more sense? @jumpman8947

Comment: I see now, i thought i had to pass in a list but there's no need because i called it on the specific instance of my list. I understand now. Thanks a bunch.